# How to get the following blogs in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

sharepoint 2013 i have multiple blog sub site.I am follwing two more blogs in shaepoint 2013.i need to get the current users following blogs.which blogs are im follwing ?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions, right now you have two questions asking the very same thing. Please delete one of them, or you risk that this one will be marked as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Their is no easy way to get this information, rather you have to right your own code(Rest, Client object models, Server object model, JavaScript object model) using the AP1s.

- [APIs for following content in SharePoint Server 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163217(v=office.15).aspx)
- [APIs for following people in SharePoint Server 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163130(v=office.15).aspx)

  Here is an example which may be starting point for your.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18580.sharepoint-2013-how-to-get-following-and-followers-of-user-by-using-jsom-or-javascript.aspx